# Error Class 'App\product' not found, laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

> Error :
> Class 'App\product' not found (View: /home/panehekm/public_html/resources/views/store/category-detail.blade.php)

Error:

> $products = \App\product::where("category_id", $category->id)->get();

```php
@php 
$products = \App\product::where("category_id", $category->id)->get();
        foreach ($products as $product) {
          $b = false;
          foreach (\App\SubcategoryProduct::where("product_id", $product->id)->get() as $sp) {
            if ($sp->subcategory_id == $subcategory->id) {
              $b = true;
            }
          }
          if ($b == false) {

            $products = $products->except($product->id);
          }
        }
@endphp
```

**help pls**

Comment: can upload you `product.php` code

Comment: Just as a sidenote. You seem to have a lot of non-view related logic in a view, which is very bad practice. You should move this somewhere else, at least in the controller if not in its own library

Answer (score 0):

Add the code `use App\Product;` to the controller being used